# Почему from не подсвечивается в IDLE?

Tags: python

```py
**From** tkinter import *

My_window = Tk()
My_window.title("Задача 1")
My_window.geometry ("300x300")

labell = Label(text="Оберіть флеш-накопичувач",
           fg="#FF298D", #колip тексту
           bg="#4EFF21", #фон надпису
           justify=CENTER, #Вирівнювання тексту
           font=30, #poзмiр символів
           )
labell.pack()
office=IntVar() #Створення групи перемикачів First
officel=Radiobutton (My_window,
                 text='Kingston', #текст перемикача 1
                 variable=office, #ім'я групи перемикачів
                 value=1,         #значення перемикача
                 fg='#0F3FFF',
                 font=16,
                 bg='#ADECFF'
                 )
office1.place (x=100, y=50)
office2=Radiobutton (My_window,
                 text='SanDisk',
                 variable=office,
                 value=2,
                 fg='#0F3FFF',
                 font=16,
                 bg='#ADECFF',
                 )
office2.place (x=100, y=90)
office3=Radiobutton (My_window,
                 text='Transcend',
                 variable=office,
                 value=3,
                 fg='#0F3FFF',
                 font=16,
                 bg='#ADECFF')
office3.place (x=100, y=130)
```

Comment: А вы не пишите его с большой буквы.

Comment: Программа с `From` и работать не будет, и подсвечиваться тоже :) Пишите `from`

Comment: А `php` то тут при чём?!

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что вы пишите `From` с заглавной буквы:

```py
From tkinter import *
```

А надо так:

```py
from tkinter import *
```

Все очень просто.